# rospack error when running pre-release builds

Tags: ubuntu, pre-release, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When submitting my stack for pre-release builds, I'm getting similar errors for all packages in the stack.

```
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only clearpath_sensors
  sh: pkg-config: not found
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'clearpath_sensors'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
    Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
```

Rospack fails, and from what I gather it's caused by an error in pkg-config. I've tried running the displayed rospack command (`/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I --deps-only clearpath_sensors`) against these packages on my own machine and this works fine. Running rosmake locally also works correctly. What am I missing?

The console log for this pre-release run can be found [on the Hudson server](http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_fuerte_clearpath_common_oneiric_amd64/7/console).

Frustratingly, everything works fine on [devel_fuerte](http://build.willowgarage.com/view/devel_fuerte/job/devel_fuerte_clearpath_common_precise_amd64/). It's only the pre-release build that's failing.

Any insight would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42058/rospack-error-when-running-pre-release-builds/) by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in the log the buildfarm is not able to find the tool "pkg-config" which is called to find compiler and linker flags for packages. When your package depends on i.e. "ros" it should pull in that dependency automatically.

Can you provide a link to the exact repository state you are trying to build? May be from a look to that it becomes clear why there is no transitive dependency to pkg-config.

--

I have to correct my previous answer: since "ros" is the build dependency of your stack you will only get it's runtime dependencies. Therefore you do not get pkg-config as a dependency of your stack.
After that I looked further where the need for pkg-config came from. Actually std_msgs is using pkg-config via backticks in the manifest.xml to fetch the compiler and linker flags. But it does not state that dependency in it's stack.xml. Therefore I have added that missing dependency to std_msgs and just released std_msgs-0.4.11 (as always: it takes some time for the debian packages to appear in shadow-fixed and than public).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) on 2012-08-29**:
The repository is at https://code.google.com/p/clearpath-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fclearpath_common. If you look at stack.xml, one of the dependencies is indeed, "ros" https://code.google.com/p/clearpath-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/clearpath_common/stack.xml.